# Bringing up network interface without IP configured in Debian, for XEN dom0

Tags: debian, xen, nic, interface

I have 3 NICs that I want to be seen by my domU, even though they're not configured in dom0.

Here's my sample lines from interfaces file

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Local network, cable labeled M3
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.184
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1

# cable labeled M1
auto eth1
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
        hwaddress ether 00:19:5B:33:86:D5
        up ifconfig eth1 up

# cable labeled M2
auto eth2
allow-hotplug eth2
iface eth2 inet manual
        hwaddress ether 00:19:5B:33:86:D3
        up ifconfig eth2 up
```

I'm trying to use multiple bridge configuration with xend, but it complains about the "Link not in running state" and interface being down, although I can see them in ifconfigs' output.

What are my options to make those NICs visible in domU without configuring them in dom0?

Comment: Show us your entire /e/n/interfaces file.  I have a strong suspicion you're doing something really unwise, because the same layout works fine for me on my dom0s.

Comment: Updated as per your request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh dear... I think you're trying to use the Xen bridging stuff, which is just dire.  Set `network-script network-dummy` in xend-config.sxp, then go with this config:

```
iface lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Local network, cable labeled M3
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.184
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1

# cable labeled M1
iface eth1 inet manual
    hwaddress ether 00:19:5B:33:86:D5

# cable labeled M2
iface eth2 inet manual
    hwaddress ether 00:19:5B:33:86:D3

auto br-eth1
iface br-eth1 inet manual
  bridge_ports eth1

auto br-eth2
iface br-eth2 inet manual
  bridge_ports eth2
```

What you then do is tell the domUs to use either the `br-eth1` or `br-eth2` bridge (as appropriate).  Given that you've got cable labelling happening, I'd change the bridge names to something more useful, like perhaps `m1` and `m2`.

Comment: I agree. As a rule of thumb, avoid using Xen networking scripts. It's not so complex to do things yourself and leads to much better results.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the idea of manually bridging interfaces didn't even occur to me. What is wrong with XEN native bridging scripts?

Comment: They're excessively complicated, and don't follow standard conventions for bridging configuration, which makes it harder to manage and maintain.

Comment: I can't vote this up enough.  The Xen bridge setup scripts are just dreadful.