# eth1 doesn't come up at boot on dom0

Tags: networking, xen, bridge

I am trying to install Xen 3.2 on Debian Lenny on a server with 2 NICs, one connected to the private LAN and the other to the Internet. This server has been in operation in a non-Xen state for a while and everything works fine. With Xen, however, networking isn't coming up properly. I'm having a hard time figuring out the proper way to configure this, as there is a lot of conflicting advice on the Xen site/wiki, mailing lists and even here.

Here are the basics: eth0 is the private network, eth1 is the public Internet. Ultimately, I want dom0 (and all domU's) to have access to both interfaces. There is currently an iptables script in place (from pre-Xen use) that sets up a firewall and port forwarding for other client machines on the private network. So even before I worry about installing a domU, I'm trying to get things working for bridging, knowing that's where I need to be.

The [Xen Networking wiki](http://wiki.xensource.com/xenwiki/XenNetworking) and the [Debian Xen wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/Xen) both point me toward using Xen's bridging scripts, but when I do this, eth1 does not come up automatically at boot time, so dom0 does not have access to the public network. It comes up fine when I `sudo ifup eth1` manually. Note that I'm not even worrying about domU's yet, and I'm well aware that the out-of-the-box Xen bridging won't do anything for eth1 <-> domU.

[This ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/27179/bringing-up-network-interface-without-ip-configured-in-debian-for-xen-dom0) advises against using the Xen bridging scripts. I tried this configuration and dom0 can't access either private or public networks.

[This mailing list thread](http://www.nabble.com/Multiple-Network-Cards-%2B-Multiple-Bridges-on-debian-lenny-td25216320.html) says that the Debian bridge-utils package should do everything I need, but it seems to imply that if I want my dom0 to be on the public network, I have to assign an address to both the real eth1 as well as the bridge. So I need to burn two public addresses in this case?

`/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth1
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 24.123.138.34
    netmask 255.255.255.248
    network 24.123.138.32
    broadcast 24.123.138.39
    gateway 24.123.138.33
    # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
    dns-nameservers 127.0.0.1
    dns-search lightyearsoftware.com

auto eth1:0
iface eth1:0 inet static
    address 24.123.138.36
    netmask 255.255.255.248
    network 24.123.138.32
    broadcast 24.123.138.39
    gateway 24.123.138.33

# Internal network
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
#   mtu 9000    # memory alloc failures with 2.6.26-2 e1000 driver

#auto br-eth0 br-eth1
#iface br-eth0 inet manual
#   bridge_ports eth0
#iface br-eth1 inet manual
#   bridge_ports eth1
```

`/etc/xen/xend-config.sxp` uses `(network-script network-dummy)` when the last 4 lines of the `interfaces` file are uncommented, `(network-script network-bridge)` otherwise.

I'm more than happy to provide any other diagnostic information that can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The Xen Networking wiki and the Debian Xen wiki both point me toward using Xen's bridging scripts"

The problem with wikis is that any idiot can edit them -- and they usually do.  The Debian Xen wiki page is wrong, so very, very wrong; I don't even have the heart to look at the Xen networking wiki.  There used to be useful networky docs in the `README.Debian` for the `xen-utils` package, but they seem to have gone walkabout at some stage.

My answer in [Bringing up network interface without IP configured in Debian, for XEN dom0](https://serverfault.com/questions/27179/bringing-up-network-interface-without-ip-configured-in-debian-for-xen-dom0) probably won't work for you because it's solving a very different problem.  You should probably re-read the question to discover the differences.

That mailing list thread is full of gibberish (and Nabble's usual brain-meltingly stupid formatting) so I'm not going to try and work out exactly where you're seeing a need to put an IP address on both the interface and the bridge, but I can assure you that you don't need to do that -- just an IP address on the bridge will be perfectly sufficient.

The simple way to fix your network config is probably to:

1. Set `(network-script network-dummy)` and then `chattr +i /etc/xen/xend-config.sxp` (to discourage you from trying to fiddle with it any more)
2. Delete the `br-*` stanzas you have currently
3. Delete the `gateway` line from the `eth0:1` stanza
4. `/allow_hotplug/d`
5. `s/eth0/br0/; s/eth1/br1/`
6. Add `bridge_ports eth0` to your now-`br0` config
7. Add `bridge_ports eth1` to your now-`br1` config
8. `/etc/init.d/networking restart`

Comment: No, I understood that your other answer was solving a different problem, but was hoping to glean enough useful information from it. Your answer here did the trick, though; thanks!